# In pycharm Pandas Datafram want to highlight specific column with specific color

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, styles

I have following code ,working in Pycharm, It not working is any basic problem? there is many similar questions in stack overflow forum, I have gone through that , I came to conclusion that ***style*** function not works in Pycharm I have to switchover to Jupiter Notebook , is it true ? please guide
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data =  pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), columns=list('ABC'))
#print (data)

def highlight_cols(x):
#copy df to new - original data are not changed
df = x.copy()
#select all values to default value - red color
df.loc[:,:] = 'background-color: red'
#overwrite values grey color
df[['B','C']] = 'background-color: grey'
#return color df
return df

data.style.apply(highlight_cols, axis=None)
print(data)

Answer (score 0):

looks like your trying to print it should be

```
import pandas as pd import numpy as np 

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), columns=list('ABC'))

def color_negative_red(val):
  color = 'red' if val < 0 else 'black'
  return 'color: %s' % color

# from the resource given I assume apply is an actual method, while the resource
# below uses applymap method
styled = df.style.applymap(highlight_cols)
# you previous code, your attempting to print instead of render.
# styled.render() #will return the css styling as string
styled
```

Personally, I like to use pycharm for personal project while, Colab or junypter I like to run quick. Here's a note book if you want to see the code in action.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1deWaFprBv3IB1NNFOHB9ce-ebAOKOBXB?usp=sharing

**NOTE**: The apply method vs applymap, the usage can be better explained in the resource below. Though, to the point the apply method is expecting an 'axis' not of Null or None; while applymap is expecting a scalar value.

Padas API reference: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html

Comment: Code is running properly, but I can not visualized answer/table. Where shall i got table which formatted by code.

Comment: you need to declare a new variable with an initialized or assigned value of `data.style.apply(highlight_cols, axis=None)` then use the new variable to virtualize your table. the `render` method. For example, `styled = data.style.apply(highlight_cols, axis=None)` would be the initialized variable that has been assigned. where you would then call `styled.render()` to virtualize table data.

Comment: If you found the answer provided helpful or resolved the issue, please mark as correct. Thanks

Comment: @MahendraVidhate code updated and included notebook to see it in action